# POJO in spring always prototype scope

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm newbie to spring.

singleton – Return a single bean instance per Spring IoC container.

prototype – Return a new bean instance each time when requested

Assume a scenario, I have to store list of entities to the database.

```
Employee e1 = new Employee();
e1.setAge(30);
e1.setName(Raj);
Employee e2 = new Employee();
e1.setAge(30);
e1.setName(Vijay);
Employee e3 = new Employee();
e3.setAge(30);
e3.setName(vinoth);
```

What spring bean scope should I go for - Singleton or prototype?

Comment: Instances of `Employee` are not managed by Spring (since you are using `new Employee()` create them.  So, they are not Spring beans.  Consequently, Spring bean scope does not apply to the `Employee` class.

Answer (score 0):

In any real world scenario the employee object would either be a method parameter for say an `EmployeeService` or `EmployeeController` or a local variable - so its really not a spring bean.

Creating a POJO as spring bean is an rare case. Most spring beans are singleton - which is also the default scope.

Comment: I'm not getting your point.any object in the Spring framework that we initialize through Spring container is called Spring Bean. Any normal Java POJO class can be a Spring Bean if it’s configured to be initialized via container

Comment: If your `Employee` class was singleton, you cant have a list of employees.